# Exception full class name is coming in Rest API json response

Tags: java, rest, web-services, postman

I have written a code which will throw the following message if the list id specify in the URL didn't find in the db. It should send a json response with error message but i am getting exception class name also with message:

Expected Output from rest API:

```
 {
        "code": 404,
        "message": "Watchlist dnd was not found"
    }
```

code:

```
@RolesAllowed({ "admin" })
    @Path("/{listId}")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @ApiOperation(value = "Returns a watchlist.", notes = "")
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "The watchlist was returned.", response = Watchlist.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "The watchlist was not found.", response = ErrorMessage.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal server error.", response = ErrorMessage.class) })
    public Watchlist getList(@PathParam("listId") String listId, @HeaderParam("x-access-token") String jwtToken,
            @Context SecurityContext sec, @Context final HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        final String sourceMethod = "getList";
        if (logger.isLoggable(Level.FINER)) {
            logger.entering(CLASSNAME, sourceMethod);
        }
        WatchlistService service = new WatchlistService(cedmPersitence);
        Watchlist list = service.getWatchList(listId);

        if (logger.isLoggable(Level.FINER)) {
            logger.exiting(CLASSNAME, sourceMethod);
        }

        return list;
    }




public Watchlist getWatchList(String listId) throws IOException,NotFoundException{

        Watchlist list = new Watchlist();
        list.setListId(listId);


        if(listId !=null) {
            HBasePersistence persistence = new HBasePersistence();
            persistence.init("watchlist");
        List<WatchlistEntry> watchListEntries = persistence.getWatchlistByListId(listId);
        if (watchListEntries == null || watchListEntries.isEmpty()) {
            throw new NotFoundException("Watchlist " + listId + " was not found");
        }
        list.setEntries(watchListEntries);

        }

        return list;
    }
```

But I am getting this response:

```
{
    "code": 404,
    "message": "class com.ibm.cedm.exception.NotFoundException:Watchlist dnd was not found"
}
```

anybody know why is it so ?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the reference:
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/NotFoundException.html#NotFoundException-java.lang.String- , when you pass the error message to a NotFoundException, surely the `Throwable.getMessage()` enrich that message with the class name.

`NotFoundException` also accepts a `Response` as parameter, so instead of passing a message you can build the response by passing the `Response`.

```
final Response.ResponseBuilder response = Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);

response.entity("Watchlist " + listId + " was not found").type("text/plain");

throw new NotFoundException(response.build());
```